# OS X: Cannot start Glassfish in debug mode any more

Tags: java, glassfish

Suddenly, Glassfish doesn't start in debug mode any more. I get the following error:

```
objc[4235]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_67.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_67.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
ERROR: transport error 202: connect failed: Connection refused
ERROR: JDWP Transport dt_socket failed to initialize, TRANSPORT_INIT(510)
JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197): No transports initialized [../../../src/share/back/debugInit.c:750]
FATAL ERROR in native method: JDWP No transports initialized, jvmtiError=AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197)
Command start-domain failed.
The DAS was stopped.
```

I have not other process running on the debugger port (9009). I'm using Java 7, Yosemite, and Glassfish (tried 3 and 4).

Comment: What are your debug-options? In my case I had "jdwp=transport=...,suspend=y" which caused the very same error! And the value was set by IntelliJ (it modified domain.xml) which took me some time to realize.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that too and reverted the changes that were made by IntelliJ. But then again, somethin else in IntelliJ wasn't working. I think I wasn't able to debug my app any more. Eventually, I switched back to NetBeans.

Comment: I think you'll have to either use two domains or start Glassfish manually and then attach IntelliJ remotely. If IntelliJ starts Glassfish it seems to require "suspend=y" (which I think is a bug).

Answer (score 1):

The error seems to be caused by using the wrong debug-options "jdwp=transport=...,**suspend=y**".
These settings are needed for local debugging (if Glassfish is started by another process, e.g. by IntelliJ).
Another option is to start Glassfish first with debug settings "server=y,suspend=n" and then attach a debugger remotely.
See this [comment to IDEA-95585](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-95585#comment=27-452970) for further explanations regarding IntelliJ.